# Outbound adapter for Webmethods integration server

Tags: java, adapter, messagebroker, eai, webmethods

I need to write Java code for outbound adapter for Webmethods integration server to connect to MQ broker. Please help me in this matter as I'm new to webmethods. I've installed Universal Messaging part of webmethods.

Comment: don't understand you question. Do you read the [webMethods broker doc](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite8_ga/Broker_and_JMS/8-0-SP1_Administering_Broker.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil, hope you figured this out already.  Integration Server has an adapter for MQ which would be by far the easiest way to integrate.